# Is it possible to run a VNC server without a GPU on linux?

Tags: linux, vnc

Is it possible to run a VNC server on a machine without any GPU, or are some GPU features necessary even when the image isn't actually sent to a hardware video output?

I guess there should be some way as it's possible on a VM - or does that use some resources of the host GPU too?

Comment: What kind of machine do you have that doesn't have a GPU?  Does it literally lack any way to hook up a monitor to it?

Comment: On which OS are you trying to achieve this?

Comment: There is no machine yet - I'm thinking about building a home server or renting a hosted server, and I'm wondering if I should get one that has a GPU if I want to occasionally use a GUI application on it. It's going to run Linux in any case.

Comment: You may find that actually getting the machine to boot without a video card is tricky.  If you are trying to get a system completely without any video controller, then you need to make sure your system will boot without it.

Comment: @Driftpeasant, I have several systems without a video controller.  If you want to access it, you use a serial connection.

Comment: @Zoredache - I myself do not have any of those systems.  Every server I've got in production at least has an onboard that I can hook VGA up to.  Even the ones I've used a serial concentrator to access had a video controller of some type, even if we weren't using it.

Comment: Of course I am stretching the definition of 'server'.  Most of the devices are acting as some kind of router/firewall/network appliance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to run xserver without a graphics card. Install a framebuffer like Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer) and x11vnc.

Here is some indepth information on x11vnc, like over ssh for encryption:

http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/

Comment: Xvfb seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a video card.  I can start tightvncserver on my [ALIX.2D13](http://store.netgate.com/-P40.aspx).  Though normally when I want a GUI application, I just do X11 forwarding via SSH.